# Yii2 use ActiveForm for Search

Tags: php, activerecord, yii2, active-form

Yesterday I ran into a problem with Yii2's ActiveForm. I'am building a search form for my site but when I load the page that lists all tha cars (here takes place the search form) it throws **Call to a member function formName() on null** exception. First I changed the DataProvider to use the $model, $dataProvider returned NULL all the time. When I dump the data that returns in $model I can see all the data that stored in the table. (So far so good)
My goal would be to print for example UserGroups as search condition.

What do you think, what could be the problem? It is clear that ActiveForm doesn't get any relevant datasource that is not empty but as is wrote I got data in $model.

**Controller file:**

```
/**
     * Aktív gépkocsik listázása
     * @return string
     */
    public function actionIndex() {
        $this->vanJogosultag(Url::current(), self::VIEW);
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Gepkocsi::find(),
        ]);

        $model = Gepkocsi::find()->all();

        return $this->render('lista', array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider, 'model' => $model));
}
```

**_search.php (partial for serach form)**

```
<!-- Gépkocsi felhasználói csoport -->
        <div class="offset col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
            <?= $form->field($model['rendszam'], 'rendszam')->textInput() ?>
        </div>
```

**View file where I include the partial into the list view**

```
<?= $this->render('_search', [
        'model' => $model
    ]); ?>
```

Thank you for Your answers! Have a nice day!

Gábor

Answer (score 0):

Why not change data provider query to search all item as model does?

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Gepkocsi::find()->all(),
]);
```

Comment: It is because I use a DetailView widget at the same page and this widget waits this kind of result. I tried but it wont work, throws this error: **The "query" property must be an instance of a class that implements the QueryInterface e.g. yii\db\Query or its subclasses.**

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution for my problem. It was totally my fault. The solution was **simply create a new instance of the Gepkocsi model and pass it to the partial** and voila it works. Thank you for your answers and your effort!